# Rails Devise token and cookie session at same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ionic-framework, devise

I have a rails web which has been using cookie session authentication (devise) from its beginning. Now, we are developing an ionic mobile application which uses the API available from the rails application.

I have considered to use JWT or token authentication for this new application but I can't find a way to combine both authentication methods, cookie and JWT. Also, both applications have different requirements. For example, in the web a user can have concurrent sessions only if he/she has a certain role. On the opposite, in the mobile application it is possible to have concurrent session without any restriction.

I have reading a lot trying to figure how to combine both methods but I can't find the way. Maybe I should consider to use only one of the methods (JWT) or use another approach (doorkeeper).

Comment: for mobile application you can use `token` based authentication and web will follow session based authentication ,did you make separate controller for API?

Comment: No, I would like to use the same controllers for both applications, if possible.

Comment: you can use two before_filter callback on controller one for session based authentication and one for token based authentication

Comment: I have thought that but I don't know to check when the request is from the web or from the mobile. Maybe with a parameter on the request but I am not confortable using a parameter in all requests.

Comment: yes its problem when to use which filter

Comment: and you have same routes for API and Web also?

Comment: I am considering in this moment which option I would choose but the API should be the same for both.

Comment: you can use token based authentication if your building single page applicaion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117539/discussion-between-reylitch-and-uzaif).

Comment: The web page is not a single page application and we are using multiple pages on the ionic application, so it is not possible what you says. I don't know exactly how cookie session works but if I use the JWT approach, are the requests sending special parameters which I could use to detect it?. For example, if I see the authentication token as a parameter, I would automatically know that the request is using the JWT approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I have found a solution. According to [refaelos](http://www.refaelos.com/post/20664288136/multiple-token-authentication-with-devise-redis) and [Zac Stewart](http://zacstewart.com/2015/05/14/using-json-web-tokens-to-authenticate-javascript-front-ends-on-rails.html), I have combined devise with JWT gem, using the last as a new strategy for the first. By this way, when I don't use JWT tokens, devise will choose the default strategy (database_authenticatable in my case). Otherwise, it will use JWT strategy.

However, when the user is not authenticated and make a post request to Session#create to get the credentials, the strategy chosen by devise/warden is database_authenticatable. In order to avoid this, I needed to add a new parameter to the request but only for this case because, as I said, when the token appears in the request, the new strategy is selected.

See also:

- [An Introduction to Using JWT Authentication in Rails](https://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-to-using-jwt-in-rails/)